# Как получить видео пользователей?

Tags: php, youtube-api

Как я понимаю, есть 2 типа каналов:

https://www.youtube.com/user/username и

https://www.youtube.com/channel/channelid

Данные с каналов можно получить, используя методы YouTube Data API. 
Например, мне нужно получить 11 видео с канала

```
$videosResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet',
  array(
    'channelId' => $chanelId,
    'maxResults' => 11,
    'order' => 'date'
  ));
```

Но если передать не id канала, а id юзера, то будет ошибка:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "youtube.search", "reason": "invalidChannelId", "message": "Invalid channel.", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "channelId" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Invalid channel." } }
```

Вопрос: как получать видео с каналов типа `youtube.com/user/username`?

Comment: В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Как получать видео с каналов типа https://www.youtube.com/user/username